# CSV file issue Couldn't store <#VALUE!> in jaar Column. Expected type is Int32

Tags: vb.net, csv

I have the following code to import data from a CSV file :

```
  Dim datatabel As New DataTable()
    datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("lidno", GetType(String)))
    datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("lidnaam", GetType(String)))
    datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("blokno", GetType(String)))
    datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("plaasno", GetType(String)))
    datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("kult", GetType(String)))
    datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("wynklas", GetType(String)))
    datatabel.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("jaar", GetType(Integer)))


    Dim parser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Wingerdbou\Plaasbeplanning\2016\VBProgram\Data\Skaalkaarte\Skaalkaarte12tot16TRASH.csv")
    parser.Delimiters = New String() {","}
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = False

    parser.TrimWhiteSpace = True

    parser.ReadLine()

    Do Until parser.EndOfData = True
        datatabel.Rows.Add(parser.ReadFields())

    Loop
```

On the second last line (datatabel.Rows.Add(parser.ReadFields()) I get the following error message :  Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <#VALUE!> in jaar Column.  Expected type is Int32.

Strangely I have used the same code for another CSV file and it worked. I think the problem lies in the second CSV file, but I cannot see the issue (I used Excel to save both as a CSV (MSDOS) and formatted the column in Excel as "General".

The part problematic CSV is looks like this (from Notepad):

lidno,lidnaam,blokno,plaasno,kult,wynklas,jaar

1023-AUR,A.G.F. AURET,1-BLY,8426,COL,BULK,2012

1023-AUR,A.G.F. AURET,1-BLY,8426,COL,BULK,2012

1023-AUR,A.G.F. AURET,1-BLY,8426,COL,BULK,2012

1023-AUR,A.G.F. AURET,1-BLY,8426,COL,BULK,2012

Any help would be appreciated.
Regards

Comment: The code works with the test data you have provided, so the only possible cause of your problem is the presence of one or more lines that doesn't follow the expected pattern in your real data.

Comment: `<#VALUE!>` almost looks like something was wrong with the data in excel before the export

Comment: @Plutonix is correct.  Your `jaar` column in Excel has a formula that is yielding `#VALUE!`. see: [#VALUE error when you add text and values in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/100825).

Comment: Ahh. Thank you. That was exactly the problem. My Excel file had a #VALUE error. I'll remember this in future. Thank you very much.